# "Slight change vs Slight rearrange"

Tags: meaning, differences

How do they differ "slight change" and "slight rearrange"? When some slight change can be possible, is it ok to be used "slight rearrange"? Is there any big difference between them?

Comment: You're using *change* as a noun. Consider *slight rearrangement*.

Comment: a *rearrangement* is a particular type of change. Not all changes are rearrangements. For example a change in color.

Comment: To illustrate @Jim's point more...I could *rearrange* '**It was a dark and stormy night**' to '**It was a stormy and dark night**'; or I could *change* it to '**It was a dark and windy night**.'

Comment: Basically, concept of "rearrangement" is to swap or shuffle among things already composed. On the other hand, concept of "change" is literally to incorporate something new. Everything is cleat to me now. Thank you all for everything you have done for me!